# Footer does fill the whole width. Scrolling in document library

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem with the footer not extending to the right side when scrolling to the right. (In a document library with way to many columns). Meaning the footer have a blank spot in the right side when scrolled to the right, and to the bottom where you can see the footer. (SharePoint 2013).

I'm using the jQuery from [Randy Drisgill's example](http://blog.drisgill.com/2013/01/sticky-footers-in-sharepoint.html) to place the footer.

I have tried almost every different css setting for `overflow / overflow-x`, for `bodycontainer`, `workspace` and `customFooter`.

Hope anyone got a solution for this, I have not found any solution for this on stackexchange, but there most be more that have this problem.

Comment: I've tried it recently myself. I just gave up. There are so many things that can go wrong with this footer. I ended up restricting the maximum width of the content area. So, now in lists with lots of columns there is a horizontal scroolbar. Not the perfect solution, but it's the best we could do... Good luck with finding a good solution.

Comment: Sometimes, the best tip is just to leave it alone...I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with HTML + CSS only Source: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

HTML

```
<div class="page-wrap">

  Content!

</div>

<footer class="site-footer">
  I'm the Sticky Footer.
</footer>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -142px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  height: 142px; 
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}
```